# Adding Legend in R using row names

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I have data frame which I want to pass first two columns rows+variable names to the legend.

Inside of `df` I have group of dataset in which they grouped with letters from `a` to `h`.

The thing I want to succeed is that something like `78_256_DQ0_a` and 
`78_256_DQ1_a` and `78_256_DQ2_a` to legends `a` and so on for other groups.
I dont know how to pass this format to the `ggplot`. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Lets say I have a data frame like this;

```
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1,function(x){
AC <- as.character(rep(rep(c(78,110),each=10),times=3))
AR <- as.character(rep(rep(c(256,320,384),each=20),times=1))
state <- rep(rep(c("Group 1","Group 2"),each=5),times=6)
V <- rep(c(seq(2,40,length.out=5),seq(-2,-40,length.out=5)),times=2)
DQ0 = sort(replicate(6, runif(10,0.001:1)))
DQ1 = sort(replicate(6, runif(10,0.001:1)))
DQ2 = sort(replicate(6, runif(10,0.001:1)))
No  =  c(replicate(1,rep(letters[1:6],each=10)))
data.frame(AC,AR,V,DQ0,DQ1,DQ2,No)
}))
```

> head(df)

```
    AC  AR     V         DQ0        DQ1        DQ2 No
1   78 256   2.0 0.003944916 0.00902776 0.00228837  a
2   78 256  11.5 0.006629239 0.01739512 0.01649540  a
3   78 256  21.0 0.048515226 0.02034436 0.04525160  a
4   78 256  30.5 0.079483625 0.04346118 0.04778420  a
5   78 256  40.0 0.099462310 0.04430493 0.05086738  a
6   78 256  -2.0 0.103686255 0.04440260 0.09931459  a
*****************************************************
```

this code for plotting the `df`

```
library(reshape2)
df_new <- melt(df,id=c("V","No"),measure=c("DQ0","DQ1","DQ2"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_new,aes(y=value,x=V,group=No,colour=No))+
geom_point()+
geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `lty = variable` to your aesthetics, like so:

```
ggplot(df_new, aes(y = value, x = V, lty = variable, colour = No)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

will give you separate lines for `DQ0`, `DQ1`, and `DQ2`.

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks for that. What about addressing row names_? is that possible:)

Comment: @aoronbarlow your data frame does not have rownames. What do you mean by that?